# After updating the tripartite style sheet, the loaded style is invalid

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser-cache

Application A loads a js file and A css file of application B. Whenever application B updates, some users of application a loads the css file of application B loses the style. Application B does not use the cdn, the file path of application B does not change, and the style is not modified. When you open Network in chrome, it is found that this style file reads the disk cache. If you read the cache, this phenomenon should not occur. Have you encountered this problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.